# Balancing between load and site stability (500 errors) with max-procs in lighttpd

Tags: php, lighttpd, 500-error

I have a rather large dynamic site running off a single lighttpd powered box (1.3 million page views per day).

But Im frequently getting random 500 errors on the site, which sometimes go away within a second or 2... or sometimes not going away until lighttpd service is restarted.

If I set the max-procs to something low... like 2-4..... the server load is relatively low.... about 2-3 (at least for the hardware and the level of traffic), yet Im getting VERY frequent 500 errors. If I raise the procs to like 6-8, the server load doubles.... but I get less of these hiccups.

I currently settled at 6... which works out okay, but I still get quite a few of these intermittent 500 errors... with a non-recovering one every few days that requires a lighttpd restart.

What can I do?

The site is php/mysql powered.

Comment: Need a lot more information: Contents of server logs, straces of the processes when they fail, the way you're spawning the PHP processes and how you're passing request to them.  And probably lots more besides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be the one that they have documented on the lighty site.

[Why is my PHP application returning an error 500 from time to time](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:PerformanceFastCGI#Why-is-my-PHP-application-returning-an-error-500-from-time-to-time)?

Comment: Interesting. Will try this out.